# Comparação de String não funciona

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma string que atualmente só recebe "ERROR" e eu fiz um if para quando ela me desse esse valor executava algumas coisas, acontece que a comparação sempre falha, mesmo as strings sendo exatamente iguais, sempre comparei string dessa forma, não entendo porque não esta funcionando:

```
                           try {
                                String mensagem = response.body().getAsJsonObject().get("error").getAsJsonObject().get("msg").toString();
                                String status = response.body().getAsJsonObject().get("status").toString();
                                //Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+mensagem);
                                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+status);
                                if(status.equals("ERROR")){
                                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, mensagem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    habilitarformgerarsenha(true);
                                }else{
                                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: Status mensagem:" + status);
                                }
                            }catch (NullPointerException e){
                                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+e);
                            }
```

LOG:

```
02-05 23:57:41.036 30711-30711/1.com.br.doup I/igr: onResponse: "ERROR"
02-05 23:57:41.036 30711-30711/1.com.br.doup I/igr: onResponse: Status mensagem:"ERROR"
```

Comment: Não capture `NullPointerException`. Ao invés disso veja qual a linha em que está a aceder a algo nulo, e dê a respetiva resolução a esse caso.

Comment: @Isac retirei o try catch, nada mudou

Comment: Não é suposto mudar, a menos de indicar a linha onde tem de facto o problema. Agora sim é suposto mostrar o erro que deu no log e respetiva linha

Comment: Não apresenta erro, não cai no catch, ele sempre cai no else, mesmo a condição sendo verdadeira

Comment: `Log.i(TAG, mensagem  + "," + status);` antes do `if` mostra o quê ?

Comment: I/igr: "Usuário inválido!","ERROR"

Comment: Mas o status tem `ERROR` ou `"ERROR"` ?. Tenha atenção pois as aspas fazem diferença, e se for esse o caso nunca irá dar `true`

Comment: Tem aspas sim fica assim "ERROR" é um string

Comment: Sim aparentemente a sua `String` já tem aspas lá dentro. Pode testar facilmente trocando o seu `if` por `if(status.equals("\"ERROR\"")){`

Comment: @Isac era isto mesmo, posta como resposta, se possível como retirar as aspas de dentro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que aparece no Log:

> onResponse: "ERROR"

A `String` que tem em `status` já tem umas aspas lá dentro o que faz com que o `if`:

```
if(status.equals("ERROR")){
```

Nunca dê verdadeiro.

Para resolver pode alterar o `if` para incluir as aspas também:

```
if(status.equals("\"ERROR\"")){
```

Note que tiveram de ser incluindas com `\"` para poder escapar as aspas iniciais.

Ou outra alternativa seria remover as aspas que já la está à custa de [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

```
status = status.substring(1, status.length()-1); //remover as aspas
if(status.equals("ERROR")){ //if normal
```

O [`substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) utilizado pega desde o segundo caractere, na posição 1, até ao penúltimo, dado por `length - 1`